# Using Amazon EC2 with Amazon S3

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have installed Wordpress on Amazon EC2 instance and trying to host it on my bucket on Amazon S3. Is there any way to host the website without using route 53? I have tried using w3 total cache to upload the static contents(cloudfront + S3), but don't know how to set up, so that i can access it with the bucket uri. would it be possible to set up like that and make it accessible through the site uri?

Comment: Could you please update your Question with more details? It seems that you wish to output Wordpress as static files to be hosted from an S3 bucket, is that correct? Could you also please clarify how you would like to access the content (eg via your own domain?), what you have tried doing so far, and what the results have been? eg What do you mean by "set up like that"? Thank you!

Comment: It is to say that can S3 + cloudfront replace a web-host? i am basically trying to build a wordpress site on Ec2, generate a static content of it using some static generator plugins and upload it S3 bucket. my question is, if the source for the cloudfront is the bucket with the static files, then can i just access the site with the URL, I give for my cloudfront distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

- Output your Wordpress blog as static HTML, and store it in Amazon S3
- Create a CloudFront distribution, with Amazon S3 as the origin
- Access CloudFront via the provided URL, and your (static) blog would appear

You can also associate a [custom DNS name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) with your CloudFront Distribution, so that it has a more friendly URL (eg `myblog.com`).

You could achieve a similar result without CloudFront, by using the **Static Website Hosting** option on your Amazon S3 bucket and associating it with a [custom DNS name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).